# Cannot create Hybrid Connection in Azure Portal

Tags: azure, biztalk, hybrid, azureportal

We are trying to set up a Hybrid Connection from an App Service and the Azure Portal behavior is quite odd. We have done this previously from another subscription; this subscription is part of a CSP (so we can't even try doing it from the old/classic portal).

1. Blade prompts us to create a new resource group even though the one it defaulted to already exists. (Like it can't populate existing resource groups?)
2. No locations are provided when navigating to the Location pane, there's a cutoff error message:

> "There are no locations available. You may not h..."

We have "owner" role on the subscription.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> his subscription is part of a CSA (so we can't even try doing it from the old/classic portal).

Do you mean **CSP** there, as in [Cloud Solution Provider](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/offers/ms-azr-0145p/)? If so, the resource provider `Microsoft.BizTalkServices` is not yet available in CSP.

Yes, the error message and how the UI flow is handled could use some improvement.

See this for more:
https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/hybridcloudbp/2016/06/29/list-of-azure-services-in-csp/

Comment: yes, sorry CSP. Unfortunate, but we can work around it..just not today :)

Comment: This should be simple enough to use instead - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-relay/relay-hybrid-connections-protocol, but definitely check if you can create it in CSP first.

Comment: we have different definitions for "simple enough" :)  Do you know if this is something that will NEVER be supported on CSPs or just not yet. Based on the link, I'm leaning toward the former.

Comment: 'Not yet' for sure. CSP is simply lagging behind it's not an incomplete stack.